# How to pass parameters to same form after form submission?

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a module that creates and displays a table and with a filter element. What I would like to do is when the user enter a string into the filter can submits it, I then use that string to filter the results of the table. What I am having an issue with is how to pass that string back into the form creation function to filter the results.

This is what I have in the submit function:

```
function submission_list_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $filter = array();
  if (isset($form_state['values']['filter_user'])) {
    $filter['username'] = $form_state['values']['filter_user'];
  }
  return $filter;
}
```

Which is not right obviously. How do I get the $filter variable to be passed back into the submission_list_form function that creates the page? This is being done with Drupal 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code, to achieve what you want.

```
function submission_list_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $filter = array();

  if (isset($form_state['values']['filter_user'])) {
    $form_state['filter']['username'] = $form_state['values']['filter_user'];
  }

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;  
}
```

The form building function should then check if `$form_state['filter']` is set.

```
function submission_list_form($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form_state['filter'])) {
    // …
  }

  // …

  return $form;
}
```

If the code doesn't work, use another array index instead of `$form_state['filter']`; it is probable that in such case the array index conflicts with the one used by Drupal or a third-party module. I would rather prefix the array index with the short module name, to be sure to avoid conflicts with other modules or future Drupal versions.

#### References

- [drupal_build_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7)

Comment: Thank-you that worked perfectly. And good point about prefixing the index array to avoid name collisions.

Answer (score 0):

In `submission_list_form_submit()`, instead of returning `$filter`, you can set this value on the `$_GET` variable, and then get this value back when you're in your form building function.

Comment: Form submission handlers and form builders are not hooks.  Furthermore, [hook_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_form/7) is a not a form builder, since it gets different parameters.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but I think you should use `variable_get` and set to pass it.
Hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't work, since the value returned from `variable_get()` is the same for all the users. What would happen if more than one user is using that form? Also, answers should not be guesses; if you are not sure, and you think it should work, it would be better to write a comment, which you are not still allowed to write for questions asked by others.